# Network manager times out using OpenVPN, but VPN is working

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to a VPN service using the gnome network manager applet. It times out when I try to do this and this is what I see in /var/log/syslog:

```
Sep 15 18:50:13 mylaptop NetworkManager[1227]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Sep 15 18:50:13 mylaptop NetworkManager[1227]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 819
Sep 15 18:50:13 mylaptop NetworkManager[1227]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Sep 15 18:50:13 mylaptop NetworkManager[1227]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Sep 15 18:50:13 mylaptop NetworkManager[1227]: <info> VPN connection 'mx2.myvpn.com.udp1194' (Connect) reply received.
Sep 15 18:50:13 mylaptop nm-openvpn[826]: OpenVPN 2.2.1 x86_64-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Dec  1 2014
Sep 15 18:50:13 mylaptop nm-openvpn[826]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sep 15 18:50:13 mylaptop nm-openvpn[826]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Sep 15 18:50:13 mylaptop nm-openvpn[826]: LZO compression initialized
Sep 15 18:50:13 mylaptop nm-openvpn[826]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sep 15 18:50:13 mylaptop nm-openvpn[826]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]169.57.0.237:1194
Sep 15 18:50:53 mylaptop NetworkManager[1227]: <warn> VPN connection 'mx2.myvpn.com.udp1194' (IP Config Get) timeout exceeded.
Sep 15 18:50:53 mylaptop nm-openvpn[826]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
Sep 15 18:50:53 mylaptop NetworkManager[1227]: <info> Policy set 'Sherrutim' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Sep 15 18:50:58 mylaptop NetworkManager[1227]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
```

However, when I run the same `.ovpn` file in the command line as root I can connect successfully. Any idea what the problem may be?